# overriding save_form in an Admin doesn't work for an inline'd Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

I override save_form to automatically populate the author field in class Grievances by using obj.author = request user.  Works great.  But then, for purposes of the inline, I try the same thing using obj.status_author = request.user.  Doesn't work - nothing is input and the sql execution fails because status_author is a required field.

The successful overriding of save_form takes place in my GrievancesAdmin for obj.author. If I try the same thing for obj.status_author, but in GrievanceStatusAdmin (which gets inlined), it does not work as nothing in input.

I have the following files:

models.py

```
class Grievances(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='grievance_author')
    firefighter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='firefighter_harmed')
    ...

class GrievanceStatus(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Grievances)
    updatetext = models.TextField(blank=True)
    action = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    status_author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='grievance_status_author')
```

forms.py

```
class UserModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    """ Override to use full name in ChoiceField """
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s (%s)" % (obj.get_full_name(), obj.username)

class GrievanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    firefighter = UserModelChoiceField(User.objects.all().order_by('last_name')) 
    class Meta:
        model = Grievances

class GrievanceStatusForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = GrievanceStatus
        fields = ('action', 'updatetext', )
```

admin.py

```
class GrievanceStatusInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = GrievanceStatus
    fk_name = 'title'
    form = GrievanceStatusForm
    list_select_related = True

class GrievancesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'firefighter',)
    inlines = [ GrievanceStatusInline ]
    form = GrievanceForm

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        ### something is wrong with the following line but i'm not sure what ###
        obj2 = super(GrievancesAdmin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
        obj2.status_author = request.user
        formset.save()

    def save_form(self, request, form, change):
        obj = super(GrievancesAdmin, self).save_form(request, form, change)
        obj.firefighter = User.objects.get(username__exact=obj.firefighter)
        obj.status_author = request.user
        if not change:
            obj.author = request.user
        obj.date_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
        return obj
admin.site.register(Grievances, GrievancesAdmin)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should try something like the following! I put a try...except block there because you may have other forms on the page as well, that don't have a `status_author` attribute!

```
class GrievancesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

   def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
       formset.save()
       if not change:
           for f in formset.forms:
               try:
                   obj = f.instance 
                   obj.status_author = request.user
                   obj.save()
                except:
                   continue
```

Comment: thanks.  that works, but whether i use that code or not, i've finally narrowed down my problem to being the line "fields = ('action', 'updatetext', )" in forms.py in the class GrievanceStatusForm.  when i specify fields and don't include my status_author (expecting it to be taken care of in the save_formset), then it crashes with the sql error about not null.  if i comment out the fields line in forms.py and let django display fields for everything in the model, then it works. but that exposes me to my user changing the author, which i don't want to do. so i'm still searching for my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For an inline admin, you probably want to override `save_formset` instead.

Comment: override save_formset within the inline?  as in -- obj = super(GrievanceStatusInline, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change) -- or within the first level Admin?

Comment: The top-level admin, `GrievancesAdmin`. This is what controls the saving of the form.

Comment: i've added in an override of save_formset to the top-level admin GrievancesAdmin. But it still does not process through. Via print statements i've figured out which line it is hanging on. please see my edited admin.py file above with the comment.  thanks.

Comment: `save_formset` doesn't actually return anything (line 603 of contrib/admin/options.py), so the line you highlighted is actually setting obj2 to `None`.